# awk or perl one liner + verify array values with awk one liner command

Tags: linux, perl, awk, ksh

Please advice how to verify with awk / perl one liner  command line the following

I want to check if the values from DATA_ARRAY array are exactly 120 if one or more values are different from 120 then awk will give false

For example

Awk will give TRUE if all values are 120

```
echo ${DATA_ARRAY[*]}
120 120 120 120
```

Awk will give FALSE if one or more values are different from 120

```
echo ${DATA_ARRAY[*]}
120 120 115 120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OR**

```
$ echo "${DATA_ARRAY[*]}" | awk '$1!=val{print "error"}' RS=' ' val="120"
```

**--edit--**

```
$ echo "${DATA_ARRAY[*]}" | awk '!f && $1!=val{print "False"; f=1}END{if(!f)print "True"}' RS=' ' val="121"
```

For Variable

```
$ my_variable=$(echo "${DATA_ARRAY[*]}" | awk '!f && $1!=val{print "False"; f=1}END{if(!f)print "True"}' RS=' ' val="120")
```

**Test**

```
[akshay@aix tmp]$ DATA_ARRAY=(120 120 120 120)
[akshay@aix tmp]$ my_variable=$(echo "${DATA_ARRAY[*]"} | awk '!f && $1!=val{print "False"; f=1}END{if(!f)print "True"}' RS=' ' val="120") 
[akshay@aix tmp]$ echo $my_variable
 True

[akshay@aix tmp]$ DATA_ARRAY=(120 120 120 125)
[akshay@aix tmp]$ my_variable=$(echo "${DATA_ARRAY[*]}" | awk '!f && $1!=val{print "False"; f=1}END{if(!f)print "True"}' RS=' ' val="120") 
[akshay@aix tmp]$ echo $my_variable
 False
```

Comment: Thanks fedorqui, I just did it

Comment: No `exit` statement has no effect actually when you use `END` block if you have any file test this command `awk 'NR==2{exit}1;END{print "I am not bothered about exit hey hey"}' file`

Comment: I get error from awk the last one code "error near line 1"

Comment: @ Eytan can you post an error, I will post what I tested just wait..it's alright fedorqui

Comment: @Awk note that to have Eytan receiving a message you have to put `@` + `name`, without any space in between.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$ awk -v d="${DATA_ARRAY[*]}"
         'BEGIN{
               n=split(d,a);
               for (i=1;i<=n;i++) if (a[i]!=120) {print "False"; exit}
               print "True"
        }'
```

#### Explanation

- `-v d="${DATA_ARRAY[*]}"` passes the array to awk as the variable `d`.
- `BEGIN{}` things to do when you do not have any stdin.
- `n=split(d,a)` split the array based on space (the default separator). The number of fields obtained is returned by `split()` and saved into var `n`.
- `for (i=1;i<=n;i++) if (a[i]!=120) {print "False"; exit} print "True"` loop through the array elements checking if the value is 120. If not, print "False" and exit. If no exit has happened, print True.

#### Example

```
$ DATA_ARRAY=(120 120 120)
$ awk -v d="${DATA_ARRAY[*]}" 'BEGIN{ n=split(d,a); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) if (a[i]!=120) {print "False"; exit} print "True"}'
True

$ DATA_ARRAY=(120 120 1)
$ awk -v d="${DATA_ARRAY[*]}" 'BEGIN{ n=split(d,a); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) if (a[i]!=120) {print "False"; exit} print "True"}'
False
```

---

To save into a variable, do:

```
myvar=$(awk -v d="${DATA_ARRAY[*]}" 'BEGIN{ n=split(d,a); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) if (a[i]!=120) {print "False"; exit} print "True"}')
```

Comment: is it possible to insert the error value to parameter in place to print it ?

Comment: Yes, sure, just do `result=$(awk ...)`

Comment: Well explained fedorqui +1

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Still one-liner.

```
[[ $(grep -wo 120 <<<${DATA_ARRAY[*]}|wc -l) -eq ${#DATA_ARRAY[*]} ]] && echo "true" || echo "fail"
```

Comment: `awk` approach fails, assume data array contains `1201` then it still gives you `true`

Comment: Ok, I clean the awk code, seems gsub is not suitable.

Comment: Ok, +1 for `grep` approach nice one.